# Problem converting net forward on caffe from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, caffe

I am trying to convert some MATLAB code to Python because I was unsuccessful in running the code on MATLAB (it crashed whenever I run it). So far I have finished converting the code and run it but the result is very wrong. So I tried to debug it and some part of the codes still gives me uncertainty since I can't check the result on MATLAB

This is the MATLAB code that I want to convert

```matlab
%Prepare images
im=reshape(im,[size(im)]); im=single(im)/255;
im_data = im(:, :, [3, 2, 1]);  % permute channels from RGB to BGR
im_data = permute(im_data, [2, 1, 3]); 

%pass images  
out_im = net.forward({im_data});
n_out=out_im{2}; al_out=out_im{1}; light_out=out_im{3};
```

This is the Python code that I created

```py
#Prepare images (rotate,flip,change color,reshape)
im=np.reshape(im,(im.shape))
im=np.float32(im)/255
#already convert to BGR on top
#im_data = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
#Dibalik lalu di rotate 90 ke kiri
im_data = np.transpose(im, (1, 0, 2)) 
im_data=np.moveaxis(im_data, -1, 0) 
im_input = im_data[np.newaxis, : , :, :]
net.blobs['data'].reshape(*im_input.shape)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = im_input
#pass images  
out_im = net.forward()
n_out=out_im['Nconv0'][0] 
al_out=out_im['Aconv0'][0] 
light_out=out_im['fc_light'][0]
```

I tried to follow the tutorial for caffe user which is the input should be (N,channel,width,height) so I convert the input into (1,3,128,128) but on the MATLAB code I believe the shape is (width,height,channel). Last time I tried to input with just 3 dimension I got error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When transpose, it is (2,0,1), not (1,0,2).

```
inputs = cv.resize(inputs,(128,128))
inputs = inputs.transpose((2,0,1))
inputs = inputs[None,:]
net.forward_all( data = inputs )
```

try this one

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing this out, but I think my transpose and moveaxis combined will be the same result as your answer so the result is still the same but just less code. I will fix it later. I already tried to your code and the output is still the same so does this mean there are no problem on this part of code then?

Comment: I think you should subtract the mean value. What network do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
inputs = cv.resize(inputs,(128,128))
inputs = inputs * 0.00390625
inputs = inputs.transpose((2,0,1))
inputs = inputs[None,:]
net.forward_all( data = inputs )
```

try this one again

Comment: I will try it later as soon as I finish fixing the transpose problem below. It seems that I have a problem with transpose, I have no idea that they change input from (w,h,d) into (d,h,w)

Comment: Hi, so apparently after correcting all the transpose I finally get the result that I wanted and since you help me point out the transpose problem I will mark the first one as the answer. I also tried your suggestion on this post but the result is very wrong. Thank you